# Stripe client secret not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

Im working on an ecommerce website that has stripe i get the client secret like this

```
const getClientSecret = async () => {
        const response = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            // Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits
            url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
        });
        setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
    }

    getClientSecret();
}, [basket])
```

the basket should be selfexplanatory but the thing is it works fine on desktop (on my laptop) but when i connect to my localhost from my phone i cant purchase it because it doesnt have a client secret the error is

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gioKn.jpg)

Im slowly going insane bit by bit and soon Im gonna develop anxiety because of this bug i got this bug 1 month ago so send help.

Comment: There are a number of ways this might be failing, you need to debug in more detail. Is your phone able to reach the `/payments/create` endpoint on the server? How are you hosting this app? If you're using eg webpack dev server this might only work locally. Do you see the request on your server with logging? Can you log the `response.data` on your phone to see what came back?

Comment: Without further information, I'd guess the axios request is failing entirely and never sets the client secret.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating a `PaymentIntent` through yout endpoint, `client_secret` should be a string, something in the form of `pi_1DnXeH2eZvKYlo2C9DtcxO4W_secret_Doc0SZOSJWkDWIooeh37DJfEA` for example. Seems like your `response.data.clientSecret` is returning `true`.